# Enemy not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I want to have one of my enemies move towards the player however they don't do that for some reason. The enemy is supposed to look at the player and when the player enters the range they should start moving towards him. My problem is that they aren't doing anything. They just stand there. Also they don't even fall when they have a rigidbody. It currently has an Animator, box collider, and a capsule collider.

Edit: I forgot to add this but the script also triggers the animations

Edit #2: Also I know that it isn't because the movement is in the if statement

(Sorry if it is bad I am a programmer noob)
This is the script responsible for the players movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mar_Tracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float InRadius = 250.0f;
    public float AttackRange = 11.0f;
    public float rocketRange = 50.0f;

    private Animator anim;

    private Coroutine RocketLouch = null;

    public GameObject Rocket;
    public GameObject Explosion;

    public SphereCollider sphereCollider;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        sphereCollider.enabled = false;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        transform.LookAt(Player); // Makes it so that the enemy looks at player 

        float dstSqr = (Player.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        bool inRadius = (dstSqr <= InRadius * InRadius);
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);
        bool inRocketRange = (dstSqr <= rocketRange * rocketRange);

        anim.SetBool("inArea", inRadius);
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", inAttackRange);

        if (inRadius)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; // (movement)
        }

        if (inRocketRange)
        {
            if (RocketLouch == null)
            {
                RocketLouch = StartCoroutine(RocketLaunch());
            }            
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RocketLaunch()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Rocket", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15f);
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;
        Explosion.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        anim.SetBool("Rocket", false);
        Destroy(Rocket);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` **every frame**? Stick with the one you got in start already ... And then is there any keyframe of the Animator in any Animation clip holding a keyframe on the position of your object? In that case the Animator will completely overrule anything else happening to it either via physics or the script .. the animator is one of the last things executed within a frame so it overwrites everything else ..

Comment: also in general if your object is supposed to be moved by physics and the rigidbody then you don't want to use `transform.position` which is simply overruling that as well

Answer (score 0):

Your using math that may be a tad to complicated for what you want to achieve and I think the issue is happening there.
Lets simplify it

```
Transform Player;
float InRadius;
float AttackRange;
float rocketRange;

void Start()
{
    // Set it at the start to optimize performance
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
}

// Use fixed Update for moving things around
// Better performance
void FixedUpdate()
{
    HandlePlayerDetection() ;
}

void HandlePlayerDetection() 
{
    
    transform.LookAt(Player); // Makes it so that the enemy looks at player 
    
    // Find the distance between the player and the transform
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
    
    // Do the boolean calculations
    bool inRadius = distance <= InRadius;
    bool inAttackRange = distance <= AttackRange;
    bool inRocketRange = distance <= rocketRange;
    
    // Lets use inbuilt functions to movement
    if (inRadius)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
    // Rocket code
    if (inRocketRange)
    {
        FireRocket();        
    }
}
    
void FireRocket()
{
    if (RocketLouch == null)
    {
        RocketLouch = StartCoroutine(RocketLaunch());
    }   
}
```

Now if you really want your enemy to walk properly I would recommend watching a tutorial on Nav Meshes. It is super easy to use and will allow the enemy to walk around objects and do propper path finding.

Comment: I tried your solution however it didn't do anything and for some reason whenever I enter its attack range it disappears but reappears when I leave. It doesn't disappear in the hierarchy either