# Enemy only moves in a line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my enemy move towards me but for some reason they head towards me for one second then doesn't change the direction they go. They will not stop even after they leave the radius. It currently has an Animator, box collider, rigidbody, and a capsule collider. Thank you for your help!

Edit: After it leaves the radius it just slides it doesn't walk

My script: (Sorry if it bad)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mar_Tracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float InRadius = 250.0f;
    public float AttackRange = 11.0f;
    public float rocketRange = 50.0f;

    private Animator anim;

    private Coroutine RocketLouch = null;

    public GameObject Rocket;
    public GameObject Explosion;

    public SphereCollider sphereCollider;

    
    void Start()
    {        
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        sphereCollider.enabled = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        HandlePlayerDetection();
    }

    void HandlePlayerDetection()
    {

        transform.LookAt(Player); 
       
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position);

        bool inRadius = distance <= InRadius;
        bool inAttackRange = distance <= AttackRange;
        bool inRocketRange = distance <= rocketRange;

        anim.SetBool("Attacking", inAttackRange);
        anim.SetBool("InArea", inAttackRange);       


        
        if (inRadius)
        {
            //transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            // neither of these methods work ^^^
        }

        
        if (inRocketRange)
        {
            FireRocket();
        }
    }

    void FireRocket()
    {
        if (RocketLouch == null)
        {
            RocketLouch = StartCoroutine(RocketLaunch());
        }
    }

    

    IEnumerator RocketLaunch()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Rocket", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15f);
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;
        Explosion.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        anim.SetBool("Rocket", false);
        Destroy(Rocket);

    }

}
```

Comment: Be sure to set `isKinematic = true` on your object

Comment: Is there any scripts at all that change this objects movement? What is the `Rocket`, and what is the object this script is attached to?

Comment: So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026399/enemy-not-moving) is solved now?